# Viewing a localhost site over a LAN

Tags: xampp, localhost, lan

I have installed and configured xampp on a server (not a web server) which has roughly 20 PCs linked up to it with a LAN.

I can view the xampp files from other PCs on the LAN but when I search the server name, followed by "/internal/homepage.php" - I get:

> 404 - File or Directory not found.
>
> The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

And when I type in "localhost/internal/homepage.php" I get:

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Why can't I vied the locally hosted files across the LAN?

**Edit**

Despite putting all the files onto a local server that is used for storage of files between 20 PCs, when I type in the IPv4 address of the connection to this network, I can view the site on other PCs, but when my laptop (which I got the IPv4 address from) is switched off, the connection cannot be made.

It seems as if it is just viewing the files from my PC but they are no longer on my PC - they're all on the server, so why should it not load them when mine is shut down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local host is only valid for the current PC (in your case the server). Try with server's IP in the other computers in lan e.g http://192.168.1.56/internal/homepage.php if that's your server's IP.

Also if your server has a firewall make sure to open port 80 for http and 3306 for Mysql

Comment: Yeah that has worked when I type the IP address in, is there a way to nickname the IP address across the network so people only have to type in e.g. "network/internal...."

Comment: if you are behind active directory then the computer name + active directory domain should work as well